# How to unhecked parent checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have nested checkboxes on my page and if I click parent checkbox child checkbox being checked it's okey so far.but if I click child checkbox I want parent click has to be unchecked how to do ?

html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>No Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="new-checkbox">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="input1"><label for="input1">kategori 1</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="input11"><label for="input11">kategori 11</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="input12"><label for="input12">kategori 12</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="input13"><label for="input13">kategori 13</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="input2"><label for="input2">kategori 2</label></li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="input3"><label for="input3">kategori 3</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="input31"><label for="input31">kategori 31</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="input32"><label for="input32">kategori 32</label></li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="input33"><label for="input33">kategori 33</label>
                            <ul>
                                <li><input type="checkbox" id="input331"><label for="input331">kategori 331</label></li>
                                <li><input type="checkbox" id="input332"><label for="input332">kategori 332</label></li>
                                <li><input type="checkbox" id="input333"><label for="input333">kategori 333</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--new-checkbox-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
.new-checkbox ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: normal 11px/16px"Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-serif;
}
.new-checkbox ul:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.new-checkbox ul li {
  margin: 3px 0;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.new-checkbox label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 2px .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px #1375b3;
  color: #1375b3;
  opacity: .50;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background: #fff;
  color: #1375b3;
  content: "\2714";
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset;
  opacity: 1;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.new-checkbox input[type=checkbox]').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      // check all children
      $(this).parent().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
      // check all parents
      $(this).parent().prev().prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      // uncheck all children
      $(this).parent().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

on [codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/grwrvp)

Comment: I would consider looking into even listeners specifically [`.on('change')`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: but how to do logically ?

Comment: I updated the answer with a fix. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new check to find if checked element has parent then check if all the children are clicked. Also it will be preferable to use `change` event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.new-checkbox input[type=checkbox]').on("change", function() {
    var $close = $(this).closest('ul').closest('li');
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // check all children
        $(this).parent().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
        // check all parents
        $(this).parent().prev().prop('checked', true);
      } else {
        // uncheck all children
        $(this).parent().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
      }
    while ($close.length) {
      $che = $close.find('ul input:checkbox');
      $checked = $close.find('ul input:checkbox:checked');
      $close.children('input').prop('checked', $che.length == $checked.length);
      $close = $($close.children('input')).closest('ul').closest('li');
      console.log($che.length, $checked.length);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.new-checkbox ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: normal 11px/16px"Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-serif;
}
.new-checkbox ul:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.new-checkbox ul li {
  margin: 3px 0;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.new-checkbox label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 2px .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px #1375b3;
  color: #1375b3;
  opacity: .50;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background: #fff;
  color: #1375b3;
  content: "\2714";
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset;
  opacity: 1;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-checkbox">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="input1">
      <label for="input1">kategori 1</label>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="input11">
          <label for="input11">kategori 11</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="input12">
          <label for="input12">kategori 12</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="input13">
          <label for="input13">kategori 13</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="input2">
      <label for="input2">kategori 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="input3">
      <label for="input3">kategori 3</label>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="input31">
          <label for="input31">kategori 31</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="input32">
          <label for="input32">kategori 32</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="input33">
          <label for="input33">kategori 33</label>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="input331">
              <label for="input331">kategori 331</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="input332">
              <label for="input332">kategori 332</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="input333">
              <label for="input333">kategori 333</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. thanks a lot @Rejith R it's working very well

Comment: hi..how about toggle like http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-treeview-with-multiple-node-selection.html version ? like a accordion..I did something but not working very well.. (click to see demo)[http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/mPrKdv]